# how to send a randomised message from a discord bot?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I've been having trouble trying to get my discord bot to send a randomised message. For some reason, my code doesn't work. When I try to run it, it says "message is not defined." I'm pretty new to coding, and the answer is probably very simple. Here is my code for the randomMessage part:

```js
const messages = ['message one', 'message two', 'message three', 'message four'];

const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * messages.length)];
```

This is the command for when someone says (prefix) random, it will then basically go to the file named "random".

```js
...
else if(command === 'random')
  client.commands.get('random').execute(message, args);
...
```

and on that file is the name of the command, the description and it also tells the bot to send (randomMessage), which should pick either message one, two, three or four?

```js
module.exports= {
    name: 'random',
    description: 'send a randomised message.',
    execute(message, args){
        message.channel.send(randomMessage)
    }
}
```

if anyone knows my mistake, I'd love to hear it. Thank you!

Comment: What is the question? You did not provide what is wrong with your code, or what doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the code in the *random* command file:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'random',
    description: 'send a randomised message.',
    execute(message, args) {
        const messages = ['message one', 'message two', 'message three', 'message four'];
        const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (messages.length - 1))];

        message.channel.send(randomMessage);
    }
}
```

If you want the randomised message to be decided on startup and not change while the bot is active, you can put the code at the top of the file:

```js
const messages = ['message one', 'message two', 'message three', 'message four'];
const randomMessage = messages[Math.floor(Math.random() * (messages.length - 1))];

module.exports = {
    name: 'random',
    description: 'send a randomised message.',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(randomMessage);
    }
}
```